# How can I preventDefault inside a callback inside an event handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, preventdefault

For example I have something like

```
$('div').on('click', '.button', function(event){
  $('.showdiv').show('fast', function(){
     var myvar = someFunction();
     if(myvar == 1){
        event.preventDefault();
     }
  });
});
```

I want to prevent the Default behaviour of the click button inside the callback of the show function (to ensure that the show div is shown before runnin the myvar function). IBut I can't make the preventDefault() works. How can I make it happen? Thanks!

Comment: Move `event.preventDefault();` before `show` line.

Comment: I think you're literally asking how to go back in time. Not possible (yet). What you can do though is prevent the event **right away**, then later re-emit it in your callback if you decide you actually wanted it.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below updates code, I think you need also need to define event in  show function.

```
$('div').on('click', '.button', function(event){
      $('.showdiv').show('fast', function(event){
         var myvar = someFunction();
         if(myvar == 1){
            event.preventDefault();
         }
      });
    });
```

Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

It should not be inside the callback.

If you put it inside the callback the default behavior would have been already fired :

```
$('div').on('click', '.button', function(event)
  event.preventDefault();{
  $('.showdiv').show('fast', function(){
     var myvar = someFunction();
     if(myvar == 1){
     }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

in the code you are not passing event as parameter.
change to

```
 $('.showdiv').show('fast', function(){
 var myvar = someFunction(event); // pass parameter
 if(myvar == 1){
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
 }
});
```